# How can we iterate over the files located in the `templates` folder with helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wanted to force the pods to restart if a configmap was modified, so I have added the following annotation in my `deployment.yaml`:

```
      annotations:
          checksum/config:   {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config.yml") . | sha256sum }}
```

It works perfectly.

I'd like to do it for all the files in my template folder.

Is there a way to do it? I have the impression we cannot iterate over the files located in the `templates` folder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that invocation works, because [`include`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) is a way to call a `define`d template, not load a file.  Do you want to include this annotation in every deployment, or force a restart if anything at all in the chart setup changes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like a restart if anything changes.

Comment: You could set an annotation with a [random value](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#randalphanum-randalpha-randnumeric-and-randascii); that would change on every deployment and force a restart.  (This isn't a typical setup.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed I have added : `timestamp: {{ now | quote }}` and it works well.

Comment: @matth3o Since you've solved it, please provide the answer in answer section. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your pods restart for each deployment, you can add:

```
      annotations:
          timestamp: {{ now | quote }}
```